# Can you prevent sort when in Row Edit Mode in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, events, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with angular and I have to support row edit mode. I've already prevented unwanted autosaving when you click elsewhere with `supressClickEdit`, but if I'm in edit mode, and the user accidentally clicks "sort" on a column header, it saves their changes - which is what I want to avoid.

There is a [sortChanged](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#sort-filter) event which I can hook into to prevent saving, but the docs say that "*grid also listens for this and updates the model*".

Is there a way to plug into this sort event pipeline to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are in edit mode, you can temporarily disable sort and re enable it after saving using a function like this -

Add   `[enableSorting]="enableSorting"` to your ag-grid div.

```
private enableSorting:boolean = true;

toggleSort() {
     this.enableSorting = !this.enableSorting;
     this.gridApi.refreshHeader();
}
```

Calling toggleSort will disable/enable sort accordingly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, it does provide a workaround, although I'd have to now manage the state of whether the enable sort is enabled from my context AND from edit mode. Thanks.

Comment: @Pratik Bhat This solution has not worked for me.  I guess this.gridApi.refreshHeader();  this line not refreshing header.  What can be done to achieve the same?